# xpath select all text but not from the side bar

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract all text from a webpage, but without information in the side bar and all its children. I also don't want to have text in the script, style or head. For the styles and scripts the following works:

```
.xpath('//*[not(self::script or self::style or self::head)]/text()[normalize-space(.)]').extract()
```

For the side bar I've started the other way around, and I've managed to get only the sidebar information like that:

```
.xpath('//*/div[@class="sidebar section"]//text()[normalize-space(.)]').extract()
```

I've tried to combine it, but like this I still get the sidebar information, and other tries threw a syntax error:

```
.xpath('//*[not(self::script or self::style or self::head or div[@class="sidebar section"])]/text()[normalize-space(.)]').extract()
```

Any ideas how to combine these to things together so that it works?

Comment: the simplest way `Xpath1 | Xpath2`

Comment: @splash58 I didn't know about this expression, thanks a lot! Do you know how I can make a reverse of the Xpath2? Like getting everything apart of the sidebar section? If I put not

Comment: `//*[not(self::script or self::style or self::head or ancestor::div[@class="sidebar section"])]`

Comment: @splash58 amazing! Thank you! do you want to put it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: student, maybe you should ahead and provide an answer yourself.